# Text Appears after progress bar - Android

Tags: java, android

I am playing around with the progress bar in android and want my text to appear after the progress bar has run. But my text appears at the same time. Its clearly in the wrong place? But where should it be?

```
package com.example.bmi;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private int progressStatus = 0;
    private Handler handler = new Handler ();
    //private TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    }


    public void calculateClickHandler(View view) {

        if (view.getId() == R.id.button1) {

            progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
            //textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
              // Start long running operation in a background thread
              new Thread(new Runnable() {
                 public void run() {
                    while (progressStatus < 100) {
                       progressStatus += 1;
                            // Update the progress bar and display the 
                            //current value in the text view
                            handler.post(new Runnable() {


                                        public void run() {
                                           progressBar.setProgress(progressStatus);
                                           //textView.setText(progressStatus+"/"+progressBar.getMax());
                                        }
                            });



                              try {
                                // Sleep for 200 milliseconds. 
                                //Just to display the progress slowly
                                Thread.sleep(50);
                              } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                  e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                 }


              }
           }).start();

              EditText weightText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                EditText heightText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
                TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);

                float weight = Float.parseFloat(weightText.getText().toString());
                float height = Float.parseFloat(heightText.getText().toString());

                float bmi = calcBMI(weight, height);
                float roundedbmi = (float) (Math.round(bmi*100.0)/100.0);

                String yoFat = fat(roundedbmi);

                result.setText("Your BMI is: " + roundedbmi + "\n" + yoFat); 


        }

    }


    private float calcBMI(float weight, float height) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return (float) (weight / (height * height));
    }


    private String fat (float bmi) {
        if (bmi < 16) {
            return "Yo Skinny ass needs some cake!";
        }
        else if (bmi < 18.5) {
            return "Stop eating them salads!";
        }
        else if (bmi < 25) {
            return "Grrrr, Just the way I like it!";
        }
        else if (bmi < 30) {
            return "Put down that cupcake!";
        }
        else {
            return "Ohh you Fat, You love the cake!";
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: `Runnable` inception!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code directly under the instantiated thread doesn't wait for the thread to finish its runnable before it's executed.

Instead, re-enter the UI thread at the end of the new thread's runnable and set your text:

```
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (progressStatus < 100) {
                // Progress update...
            }

            // Progress finished, re-enter UI thread and set text
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    EditText weightText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                    EditText heightText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
                    TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);

                    float weight = Float.parseFloat(weightText.getText().toString());
                    float height = Float.parseFloat(heightText.getText().toString());

                    float bmi = calcBMI(weight, height);
                    float roundedbmi = (float) (Math.round(bmi*100.0)/100.0);

                    String yoFat = fat(roundedbmi);

                    result.setText("Your BMI is: " + roundedbmi + "\n" + yoFat);
                }
            });
        }
    }).start();
```

Comment: Thank Pete Schmitz - That was perfect!

Comment: Pete Schmitz, any idea how to make the progress bar disappear once done?

Comment: `progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);` Should do the trick. Just make sure it's inside one of the Runnables that are being posted from the Handler.